# Trouble Launching PDF Viewer (Polaris) on Android 4.1 (Samsung)

Tags: android, pdf, android-activity, android-4.2-jelly-bean

We are creating an Activity to view a PDF file on Android Jelly Bean 4.1, and the Samsung Galaxy S3 launches Polaris Viewer by default. The first time we do this, it works. But the second time we do it, we get this error:

```
E/ActivityThread( 6788): Activity
com.infraware.polarisoffice4.viewer.PDFViewerActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.infraware.polarisoffice4.viewer.PDFViewerActivity$2@4219c850 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
E/ActivityThread( 6788): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.infraware.polarisoffice4.viewer.PDFViewerActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.infraware.polarisoffice4.viewer.PDFViewerActivity$2@4219c850 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:792)
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:593)
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1254)
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1241)
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1235)
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:372)
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at com.infraware.polarisoffice4.viewer.PDFViewerActivity.onCreate(PDFViewerActivity.java:109)
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) E/ActivityThread( 6788):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
E/ActivityThread( 6788):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If we install Adobe Reader, then we don't get this exception (even if we still choose Polaris as the viewer in the dialog box). If we uninstall Adobe Reader, the exception comes back.

If we kill our process and restart, we'll be able to view one PDF in Polaris, but then we'll get the exception when we look at a second PDF. (Doesn't matter what PDF we view: the first one we view will open, the second one will not.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like Polaris is broken.

Comment: Agreed. This is a problem in Polaris, not your app.

Comment: That was our guess, too, especially since our code works fine with other readers. However, the practical fact is that there are millions of Galaxy S3's out there with this installed as the default reader. So if we could find a work-around, that would be awesome. (Also, Polaris seems to have no support contact on their web site.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we could not fix the problem, we decided to just check before we hand off the PDF to be viewed to see if Polaris is the only viewer installed. If it is, we suggest the user should go get Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it doesn't going back to the activity after it opens the one pdf.
try to get back to that activity after it closes the that pdf and try to opens new one.

Answer (score 0):

This error normally occurs when you programmatically register a `BroadcastReceiver` with an `IntentFilter` and then forget to unregister it. Make sure you unregister the receiver before your Activity is removed by the system (such as `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`). Alternatively, you can unregister the `BroadcastReceiver` after one broadcast by doing this:

```
@Override public void onReceiver(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.unregisterReceiver(this);
    /* ... */
}
```

Just make sure that if the broadcast is never sent, you unregister the receiver somewhere else before the `Activity` is shut down.